# Selenium: grab innerHTML of elements that are below other elements

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to grab only certain li tags on a page that needs constantly to be scrolled to load new li tags. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div>
     <ul>
          <li> INFO_1 </li>
          <li> INFO_2</li>
          <li> INFO_3 </li>
          <li> INFO_4 </li>
          <li> INFO_5 </li>
          <li> INFO_6 </li>
          <li> INFO_7 </li>
          <li> INFO_8 </li>
          <li> INFO_9 </li>
          <li> INFO_10 </li>

     <ul>
</div>
```

After scrolling down, 10 new li tags are loaded: INFO_11 to INFO_20. Then again for INFO_21 to INFO_30. etc. etc.

I want to only grab those 10 li tags as they are loaded. Rinse and repeat for however many I need to load. My first instinct is to pass it to BeautifulSoup and just find_all('li'), count every 10 and go on. Is there a simpler/ more elegant way within Selenium?

EDIT:
This is what I am using to scroll. The element I'm scrolling in is a div pop up. So the way I got around it was finding the 10th `<li>` tag and scrolling to it.

```
for i in range(10, 100, 10):

     #xpath of the last <li> tag
     xpath = '/html/body/div[16]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[%s]' %(str(i))

     #Finding the element for Selenium
     last_li_tag = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

     #Scrolling to the element
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", last_li_tag)

     #waiting for pop up to load the next 10 tags
     time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading addition `<li>` elements at runtime, you already have them as javascript objects. You don't need to append them to the Document and select them.

For the initial 10 elements you can do:

```
<div>
     <ul class="u_list">
          <li> INFO_1 </li>
          <li> INFO_2</li>
          <li> INFO_3 </li>
          <li> INFO_4 </li>
          <li> INFO_5 </li>
          <li> INFO_6 </li>
          <li> INFO_7 </li>
          <li> INFO_8 </li>
          <li> INFO_9 </li>
          <li> INFO_10 </li>

     <ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll ("u_list li");
```

This will select all the `<li>` present in the `<ul>`

Comment: I see, but I don't actually want all the `<li>` present in the `<ul>` after each load. I just want the newly loaded ones. Is there some kind of list subtraction I could use? Like `current_load - last_load = new_load`?

Comment: @tjblue Can you add the code used too load the new `<li>` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the text for #11 through #20:

```
texts = driver.execute_script("""
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('div li')].slice(10,20).map(li => li.innerText)
""")
```